# How to change name in sidebar React-Admin

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

Is it possible to change the name in the sidebar ?

[image: example]

I need to translate it for my non-developers co-workers

I tried to add a "label" on the `ResourceGuesser` but no result.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the community on React-Admin is really small, it is hard to find answers.

I found a solution, I share it in case it helps :

On `Resource` set `options={{ label: 'YourLabel' }}`